# Rails 3 Factory_Girl Factory not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, factory-bot

I have to admit that I am new to testing and so am trying out my first few Rspec with Factory Girl tests. All is going well until I try and use factory girl.

My config is as follows

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

spec/models/role_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Role do
  it "is valid" do
    role = FactoryGirl.build(:role)
    expect(role).to be_valid
  end
end
```

spec/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do   
  factory :role do
    rolesymbol "tst-admin"
    name "test admin"
  end
end
```

However when I run bundle exec rspec or rake spec I get the following error

```
Failures:

  1) Role is valid
     Failure/Error: role = FactoryGirl.build(:role)
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: role
     # ./spec/models/role_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

To me FactoryGirl seems to be working, role is defined correctly, and the spec normally works, so I'm at a loss as to what is going on. Any ideas?

Michael

Comment: What happens if you use build(:role) instead of FactoryGirl.build(:role). This will use the rspec helpers for FactoryGirl instead of directly calling FactoryGirl

Comment: Nice idea but same issue. Is there a way to find out what Factory Girl has registered. I have this nasty feeling that the factory is not being registered.

Comment: Maybe a bug with using a single file for factories. Try moving factories.rb to spec/factories/roles.rb (note the plural of the filename, gets me every time)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party with this one, but I had the same problem when trying to use FactoryGirl with RSpec in a Rails engine.  I solved the problem by explicitly setting the factory girl definitions path in my spec/spec_helper.rb file

```
FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.expand_path('../factories', __FILE__)]
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Directory structure is as you'd expect:

```
root/
  spec/
    spec_helper.rb
    a_spec_file.rb
    factories/
      my_factory.rb
```

According to the FactoryGirl docs, this structure should work out of the box (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#defining-factories).  I've not investigated why this isn't the case for me.  (First reply on SO too, so apologies if there's anything wrong here!)

Answer (score 0):

Try add require 'factory_girl' to your factories.rb?

Comment: yeah i tried that too, but get the same result. also tried require 'factory_girl_rails'

Comment: OK, a bit of a cop out but I moved to Fabrication and it's working well. Will continue to see what is going on with Factory Girl though

Answer (score -1):

I'm even later to the party, but I solved this by moving the `factories` directory to the (now) more standard path of `spec/support/factories` - rspec now picks it up without any further need for telling it where to look.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I still have the problem with rspec not finding the factory defenition.

Comment: It might not have worked for you, but it did work for me, and it's thus a valid answer, helpful to some. Downvotes are for "This answer is not useful" ... which it is - not everyone will be helped by an answer, but it's still useful to those that are. ie this is not the kind of answer that people should be downvoting on, so you might want to keep your reputation for people that answer with "you're stoopid" or the equivalent ;)